# Created View with some constraint but it doesnt appear when insert

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

I have created the view with some constraints in Oracle 12c. But when I insert values which violate the constraint also be able to insert from the view. It seems like a loophole.

--Create view Emp_1

```
CREATE VIEW Emp_1
AS
SELECT Empid, Ename, Salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary < 25000
```

This view is to show only employees who are having less than 25000 for salary.

But when I insert employee who have more than 25000 as salary, View allows me to insert(this is incorrect). but it doesn't appear when i query the view(this is correct)

Is this as design or what do i can do to overcome this?

Technically this is a insert-able view. so it allows to insert. But conceptually user can see only employees who have salary less than 25000. So it does not allow to insert more than the condition.

Please correct me if I am wrong and please help.

Comment: The view shows data: so the WHERE clause filters rows from the underlying table.

Answer (score 3):

Friends thanks for the help. I found it now.

You can use `WITH CHECK OPTION CONSTRAINT` to over come this.

```
CREATE VIEW Emp_2 
AS
SELECT Empid, Date_Joined, Salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary < 25000
WITH CHECK OPTION CONSTRAINT Emp_2_Salary_Constraint;
```

Then it shows this error when you are violating it.

> SQL Error: ORA-01402: view WITH CHECK OPTION where-clause violation

Answer (score -1):

You will have to add the constraint on the `employees` table. A view is just a representation of the query. It does not have an assigned storage, and since the underlying table do not have any such constraint, you are able to insert that data. So the design and output is as it should be.